# Delphi UDPClient example -> ArtNet communication and parser

Tags: delphi, osc, dmx512

Recently I started a project where I need to combine OSC with ArtNet protocol. While OSC (Open Sound Control) has a few examples and documentation available, and the vvvv group also wrote Delphi parser which works really good, the ArtNet - Ethernet DMX protocol - has practically no support or, better said, example for delphi at all.
The only thing I managed to found was this: http://mbed.org/users/okini3939/code/DmxArtNet/docs/c59dc374fc64/DmxArtNet_8cpp_source.html
which seems incomplete and I can't get it done at all. Contacting the author was a shot in the dark...

Anyway, the main thing is in byte encoding before sending them via UDPClient.
Now, since this is basically the same way the OSC works, I guess it's not that big deal, especially since apart from OSC, the ArtNet only needs to SEND tose bits via UDPClient, and does not receive nothing at all (with OSC, most of the parser was about receiving and decoding the packet...)
But, along with the fact that I dare to say "it's not a big deal", I do have to say that at the same time I'm not familiar with how to do it at all.

Here at page 22 and 23 is the ArtDmx table with byte format informations...

www.artisticlicence.com/WebSiteMaster/User%20Guides/art-net.pdf

I think this is what I'd have to do in order to send commands...

Does anyone know anything about it, or have some time to give it a quick look on how it works, and maybe even give an example on how could I send the data from delphi's app...?

Thanks!

MarcS

***EDIT:***
Looks like their site is down, since the link to pdf doesn't work anymore, however I still have a copy of it opened, so I'll copy the contents below:

ArtDmx packets can be broadcast, but it is not recommended. Significant network efficiency gains can 
be achieved by unicasting ArtDmx. When ArtDmx is Unicast, the following rules must be used:
The transmitting device must regularly ArtPoll the network to detect any change in universe switch 
settings. If the transmitting device opts to Unicast, then it must Unicast ArtDmx to all nodes that are 
subscribed (In the ArtPollReply) to that universe. Subscribed means any universes listed in both 
the Swin and Swout array.
If there are no subscribers to a universe that the transmitter wishes to send, then the ArtDmx may be 
broadcast. Implementers should provide for dynamic change between Unicast and broadcast. If the 
number of universe subscribers exceeds a given number, it may become more efficient to broadcast. 
Use of unicast only is mandatory for systems using greater that 30 universes.
Table:
http://shrani.si/f/2c/GQ/3NF9rewr/artnet-udp-table.png

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're asking here: are you having trouble writing code to parse... something? What code have you currently got, and what problems are you having with it? Please include code snippets, and a clear description of the problem and what you've tried. Remember while all the stuff (ArtNet etc) is in your head most of us have no idea, and we're not in your head, so we need a good explanation.

Comment: As said in the first paragraph, and hoped that it'd be clear enough, I have nothing so far.
The ArtNet is way of communicating through UDP protocol. The only thing I found about ArtNet usage in Delphi, is that first link, which doesn't work. Investigating what it actually does is almost impossible, since I believe that some units are missing...
The goal here is to find someone, who understands how the bytes are arranged and encoded before sent through UDPClient. Basically, example with a button, which OnClick sends value 127 to address 256 on universe 1 at IP 127.0.0.1;

Comment: Oh, and there are maximum 8 universes used usually, 512 addresses available at each universe, and 0 to 255 is value range for each address...

Comment: So no luck here...? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a while, one of main VVVV developers, Joreg, wrote thing down to delphi units, so big thanks to them and the vvvv team.

https://github.com/vvvv/DelphiArtnet

And here's a thread: http://vvvv.org/forum/delphi-artnet-dmx-support...#comment-110297

Hope this helps to anyone else!